# SMART vs badblocks, who is right?

Tags: hard-drive, smart, bad-blocks

I have and semi-old hdd (magnetic one, not ssd) and I intended to use it as system drive for my new NAS.

So I've run SMART selftest on it and it ended with status "Completed: read failure". However, badblock complete the destructive test (so 4 passes) over the drive without errors. Which of those two programs is more likely to be right?

Comment: How much do you value a stable operation of your NAS?

Comment: I do. I just don't understand how those two tools can give different answers.

Comment: They are each performing different tests.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Think about what you're asking...

*"Which of these tools is going to give me the best result on a disk of questionable health?"*

If the disk is this unhealthy and reporting errors from *either* of these tools, you should not use it.

Neither S.M.A.R.T. nor badblocks is capable of detective every disk failure condition, but as a general rule, errors are bad.

So proceed at your own risk, but the right thing to do is to find another drive to use for this purpose.